# Artifactory upgrade 6.16.2 -> 7.12.6 failing with Application could not be initialized: UNAVAILABLE: Network closed for unknown reason

Tags: windows, artifactory

When upgrading Jfrog Artifactory from 6.16.2 -> 7.12.6 on a Windows machine, following the official instructions ([Link](https://www.jfrog.com/confluence/display/JFROG/Upgrading+Artifactory#UpgradingArtifactory-WindowsUpgrade)) i am getting the following error in `artifactory-service.log`

```
2021-01-23T12:22:20.896Z [jfrt ] [ERROR] [87face30ccb5d82c] [ctoryContextConfigListener:126] [art-init            ] - Application could not be initialized: UNAVAILABLE: Network closed for unknown reason
java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException: null
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance0(Native Method)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.java:45)
    at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Constructor.java:490)
    at org.artifactory.lifecycle.webapp.servlet.ArtifactoryContextConfigListener.configure(ArtifactoryContextConfigListener.java:265)
    at org.artifactory.lifecycle.webapp.servlet.ArtifactoryContextConfigListener$1.run(ArtifactoryContextConfigListener.java:122)
Caused by: org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanInitializationException: Failed to initialize bean 'org.artifactory.security.access.AccessService'.; nested exception is io.grpc.StatusRuntimeException: UNAVAILABLE: Network closed for unknown reason
    at org.artifactory.spring.ArtifactoryApplicationContext.initReloadableBeans(ArtifactoryApplicationContext.java:302)
    at org.artifactory.spring.ArtifactoryApplicationContext.refresh(ArtifactoryApplicationContext.java:284)
    at org.artifactory.spring.ArtifactoryApplicationContext.<init>(ArtifactoryApplicationContext.java:174)
    ... 6 common frames omitted
Caused by: io.grpc.StatusRuntimeException: UNAVAILABLE: Network closed for unknown reason
    at io.grpc.stub.ClientCalls.toStatusRuntimeException(ClientCalls.java:262)
    at io.grpc.stub.ClientCalls.getUnchecked(ClientCalls.java:243)
    at io.grpc.stub.ClientCalls.blockingUnaryCall(ClientCalls.java:156)
    at com.jfrog.router.v1.registry.ServiceResourceGrpc$ServiceResourceBlockingStub.registerService(ServiceResourceGrpc.java:281)
    at org.jfrog.access.accessrouterclient.RouterClientImpl.registerService(RouterClientImpl.java:69)
    at org.jfrog.access.client.grpc.RouterGrpcClientImpl.registerService(RouterGrpcClientImpl.java:41)
    at org.jfrog.access.client.AccessClientBootstrap.<init>(AccessClientBootstrap.java:138)
    at org.artifactory.security.access.AccessServiceImpl.bootstrapAccessClient(AccessServiceImpl.java:1290)
    at org.artifactory.security.access.AccessServiceImpl.lambda$bootstrapAccessClient$23(AccessServiceImpl.java:1251)
    at io.vavr.control.Try.mapTry(Try.java:634)
    at io.vavr.control.Try.map(Try.java:585)
    at org.artifactory.security.access.AccessServiceImpl.bootstrapAccessClient(AccessServiceImpl.java:1251)
    at org.artifactory.security.access.AccessServiceImpl.initAccessService(AccessServiceImpl.java:421)
    at org.artifactory.security.access.AccessServiceImpl.initAccessClientIfNeeded(AccessServiceImpl.java:410)
    at org.artifactory.security.access.AccessServiceImpl.init(AccessServiceImpl.java:403)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:566)
    at org.springframework.aop.support.AopUtils.invokeJoinpointUsingReflection(AopUtils.java:344)
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.invokeJoinpoint(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:198)
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:163)
    at org.springframework.transaction.interceptor.TransactionAspectSupport.invokeWithinTransaction(TransactionAspectSupport.java:367)
    at org.springframework.transaction.interceptor.TransactionInterceptor.invoke(TransactionInterceptor.java:118)
    at org.artifactory.storage.fs.lock.aop.LockingAdvice.invoke(LockingAdvice.java:76)
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:186)
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.JdkDynamicAopProxy.invoke(JdkDynamicAopProxy.java:212)
    at com.sun.proxy.$Proxy231.init(Unknown Source)
    at org.artifactory.spring.ArtifactoryApplicationContext.initReloadableBeans(ArtifactoryApplicationContext.java:300)
    ... 8 common frames omitted
2021-01-23T12:22:22.687Z [jfrt ] [ERROR] [                ] [o.a.w.s.ArtifactoryFilter:213 ] [http-nio-8081-exec-5] - Artifactory failed to initialize: Context is null
```

http://localhost:8082/ui is reachable, and showing "JFrog Platform will be available shortly" With Router as healthy, and Access, Event and Metadata as Unhealthy Peer with message "Service is healthy; there are missing services: jfrt,jffe"

http://localhost:8081/ shows the startup image for Artifactory for a while, and then throws a 500-error.

The rest of the log looks ok ,and i can't find anything in other logs either.

Comment: based on this statement "io.grpc.StatusRuntimeException: UNAVAILABLE: Network closed for unknown reason" I notice a GRPC issue, grpc basically uses the http2 and is the server supports http2? Also, check if there are any internal tool which might be blocking the grpc requests

Comment: Did you learn anything about this JFFE service?
I have the same status message but no Idea what it means. And I don't know anything that should have been done with the server reacently.

Answer (score -1):

Remove the following line:

```
artifactory.access.client.serverUrl.override
```

From:

```
$ARTIFACTORY_HOME/var/etc/artifactory/artifactory.system.properties
```